# Save route or map layer on Google Maps API v3

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, kml

Currently I'm developing an Android app that uses the GMaps v3 API to draw a route and calculate the kilometers along that route. I was wondering if there is any way to save such route into a KML or a file of sorts into the device, so it can later be loaded into it.
Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm, you're referring to implementing Google Maps in JavaScript in a `WebView`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes. That's how you use the v3 API.